# How to use bookdown.org with github?

Tags: github, github-pages, bookdown

I am trying to create a book on Github and honestly I don't have the time to learn how to code and dig into all the new terminology/technology and learn the in and outs of Github as it's really not user-friendly.

All the tutorials are too dense and not suited for beginners. I just want to generate content for my book. How can I do this?  I'm pretty good at just taking a template and adapting it to my needs, but I can't even get a template to work.

- I've installed the bookdown package in R and have opened up the sample book in R.  How do I get this sample book onto Github website?  I just uploaded all the files and when I go to my website, it just takes me to README.md
- I am using Github through my browser and don't plan on installing whatever Github software there is and all that kind of stuff.  I really don't have time to dig into how to use Github.  So any tutorial will require me using Github through the browser.
- When writing content for my book, is there a way to do it on the Github, or is doing it in Rstudio the easiest way?
- I don't have much desire to upload my book to bookdown.org.  Can I still build my website on github?
- Do I need to convert Rmd files to md files?  How do I do that?

There are plenty of books out there on Github (bookdown.org show cases many).  I believe you are able to view the files/code and what not on Github, so it may be pretty easy to just grab a couple necessary files there.  I don't know which ones are important, and even if I did, I don't know how to get it to work with my Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fork the [`rstudio/bookdown-demo`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) and make it your own GitHub repository.

From there, follow [`yihui/bookdown/get-started.html`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/get-started.html), with, at a minimum:

1. Download the GitHub repository https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo as a Zip file, then unzip it locally.
   So no need for "Git/GitHub software" there.
2. Install the RStudio IDE. Note that you need a version higher than 1.0.0. Please download the latest version if your RStudio version is lower than 1.0.0.
3. Install the R package bookdown:

   ```
    # stable version on CRAN
    install.packages('bookdown')
    # or development version on GitHub
    # devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
   ```
4. Open the bookdown-demo repository you downloaded in RStudio by clicking `bookdown-demo.Rproj`.
5. Open the R Markdown file `index.Rmd` and click the button `Build Book` on the Build tab of RStudio.

Try that with a minimal example like [`yihui/bookdown-minimal`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-minimal)

Comment: Ok, I did that, downlaoded xelatex, pandoc, tinytext, and am still having errors, will have to post another question to solve.

Comment: And then I tried "knit" and then publish and Rstudio needs to connect to some server, which makes me wonder if I needed to even download pandoc and xelatax or I just instealled bloatware...

Comment: The error I get of I click on "build" is: output file: bookdown-demo.knit.md

Error: LaTeX failed to compile bookdown-demo.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"xelatex"' not found
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.

Comment: @we_are_all_in_this_together OK, let me know the link of your new question

Comment: Well I still can't get a template website

Comment: I'll just give you the pts for now.  I don't want to feel obligated to check back within 7 days.  Thanks for the help